# How to encrypt post request body in flutter web client and php backend

Tags: php, flutter, security, encryption, flutter-web

Consider I have a map, that created by my flutter web application and my dart code, something like this:

```
  var data = {
    "name": "amir abbas",
    "user_name": "amir_a14",
  };
```

And I need send it to my backend, currently I am send it like this:

```
var url = Uri.parse('https://my-domain.test/myApi.php');
http.post(url, body: data);
```

And users can see all of the requests, including headers, tokens, bodies and urls in inspect element, and they can modify bodies and send fake requests to my backend.

My goal is that users can't modify request bodies, I need encrypt bodies before sending and decrypt it on my backend server.

But is there any way to encrypt the bodies that users can't change my map values at all?
How can I do that?

My backend server written in php.

Comment: you params in JSON format or in form data? Include backend logic as well

Comment: You cannot stop anyone from sending arbitrary HTTP requests to a publicly reachable server. You also cannot stop anyone from extracting any data present in their browser (and on their device in general).

Comment: @Peter Yes, but I want to encrypt generated data in my app, and the users should not be able to generate encrypted data like that.

Comment: That's impossible to do *on their devices*. Anything that happens on their devices can be manipulated and/or replicated. You simply don't control them. What you can do is encrypt something on the server, send it to the client, and then have the client echo it back to the same or some other server.